# Bootstrap datetimepicker does not open

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, .net-4.5, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I am using two calendars on the page, start and end dates, using Bootstrap date time picker. Oddly, it works fine when run locally from within Visual Studio 2017; but when deployed clicking text box or icon has no effect.

I checked for similar problem online and tried all suggestion: using class name instead of div id, checking order of js/css includes, ... but nothing helped.

I checked developer console for errors and see: "EventLog.aspx:353 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).datepicker is not a function" at the following line:

```
$('#divStartDate').datepicker({
```

I read that this could be caused if there are multiple references to jquery and I can't see it, unless one of the other plugins I am using is using it as well.

This is .Net application and in master file I have:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.9.0/moment-with-locales.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.14.30/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.19/sorting/datetime-moment.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.14.30/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.3.0/css/datepicker.min.css">

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
```

In the aspx page using calendars:

```
<div class="col-sm-2">
    <div>
        <label for="tbStartDate">Start Date</label>
        <div id="divStartDate" class="input-group date startdate">
            <input runat="server" clientidmode="static" type="text" id="tbStartDate" class="form-control" style="cursor: pointer">
            <span class="input-group-addon" style="cursor: pointer">
                <i class="fa fa-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-2">
    <div>
        <label for="tbEndDate">End Date</label>
        <div id="divEndDate" class="input-group date enddate">
            <input runat="server" clientidmode="static" type="text" id="tbEndDate" class="form-control" style="cursor: pointer">
            <span class="input-group-addon" style="cursor: pointer">
                <i class="fa fa-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
....
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () 
        // I tried replacing #divStartDate with .input-group.date.startdate
        $('#divStartDate').datepicker({
            format: 'mm/dd/yyyy',
            useCurrent: true,
            autoClose: true,
            allowInputToggle: true,
            endDate: '+0d',
            ignoreReadonly: true,
            showTodayButton: true,
            viewMode: 'days'
        }).on('changeDate', function (e) {
            $('#hfStartDate').val(e.format());
            $(this).datepicker('hide');
        });

        $('#divEndDate').datepicker({
            format: 'mm/dd/yyyy',
            useCurrent: false,
            autoClose: true,
            allowInputToggle: true,
            endDate: '+0d',
            ignoreReadonly: true,
            showTodayButton: true,
            viewMode: 'days'
        }).on('changeDate', function (e) {
            $('#hfEndDate').val(e.format());
            $(this).datepicker('hide');
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: `bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js` added 2 times, please remove one

Comment: Check your script tag, I see that `bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js` used twice. Remove one of the script tag and see if it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have some errors in your code which you should avoid:

- include any `library` **only once**, you have added `bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js` 2 times.
- You have included `datetimepicker` library then you **should initialize it as per [documentation](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/)**  for e.g. `$('#divStartDate').datetimepicker();` not as `datepicker()`.
- **Use `maxDate`**, `endDate` is not a valid option for [datetimepicker](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/).
- see [`format`](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Options/#format) option, you have to give capital values because it refers to `moment.js` format option [see here for options](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/).

and now the **solution** is as below:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#divStartDate').datetimepicker({
            format: 'DD/MM/YYYY',
            useCurrent: true,
            keepOpen: true,
            allowInputToggle: true,
            maxDate: new Date(),
            ignoreReadonly: true,
            showTodayButton: true,
            viewMode: 'days'
        });

        $('#divEndDate').datetimepicker({
            format: 'DD/MM/YYYY',
            useCurrent: false,
            keepOpen: true,
            allowInputToggle: true,
            maxDate: new Date(),
            ignoreReadonly: true,
            showTodayButton: true,
            viewMode: 'days'
        });
});
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.9.0/moment-with-locales.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.14.30/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>


<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.3.0/css/datepicker.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />

<div class="col-sm-2">
    <div>
        <label for="tbStartDate">Start Date</label>
        <div id="divStartDate" class="input-group date startdate">
            <input runat="server" clientidmode="static" type="text" data-date-end-date="0d" id="tbStartDate" class="form-control" style="cursor: pointer">
            <span class="input-group-addon" style="cursor: pointer">
                <i class="fa fa-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-2">
    <div>
        <label for="tbEndDate">End Date</label>
        <div id="divEndDate" class="input-group date enddate">
            <input runat="server" clientidmode="static" type="text" data-date-end-date="0d" id="tbEndDate" class="form-control" style="cursor: pointer">
            <span class="input-group-addon" style="cursor: pointer">
                <i class="fa fa-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, removing duplicate library reference and changing datepicker to datetimepicker fixed the issue. I also had to remove autoClose:true. The only minor issue right now is the the "Next Month" right chevron has a yellow background. Used Chrome's console but can't see where it is coming from.

Comment: Never mind about the right chevron. Because end date on calendars are set to today, users cannot advance to next month when they are already viewing current month. I guess the yellow background is a visual indication of that.

Comment: @NoBullMan, yes the yellow background is there because the maxDate has been  set to today and if you want to select date greater than today then you can remove maxDate option from initialization, thanks.